# jQuery Popup Bubble/Tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a "bubble" that can popup when the `onmouseover` event is fired and will stay open as long as the mouse is over the item that threw the `onmouseover` event OR if the mouse is moved into the bubble. My bubble will need to have all manners of HTML and styling including hyperlinks, images, etc.

I've basically accomplished this by writing about 200 lines of ugly JavaScript but I would really like to find a jQuery plugin or some other way to clean this up a bit.

Comment: @bluefeet Off topic? Seriously? The guy asked a question about how to shorten his 200 lines of code by using JQuery, and it's been used nearly a quarter of a million times (just solved my problem) and you mark it off topic? What about this invites any more opinionated answers than any other question?

Comment: @ChrisSharp Did you read the reason why it was closed? It specifically asks for "a good jQuery plugin for doing fancy bubbles".  Questions asking for recommendations are off-topic, but if you think this could be rewritten to make it on-topic, then feel free to suggest an edit to get it into shape.

Answer (score 159, accepted):

[Qtip is the best one I've seen.](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/) It's MIT licensed, beautiful, has all the configuration you need.

My favorite lightweight option is [tipsy](https://github.com/jaz303/tipsy). Also MIT licensed. It inspired [Bootstrap's tooltip plugin](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips).

Comment: By far the best.  One line of code vs all the other huge solutions others have offered.  I hope this response gets voted up.

Comment: Qtip has compatibility problems with jQuery 1.4+.  Simple one-line fix to qTip plug in fixes it though.  See here: http://craigsworks.com/projects/forums/thread-solved-qtip-1-0-0rc3-does-not-work-with-latest-jquery-release

Comment: I looked at Qtip today and while it does work there are some down sides: hasn't been updated in a while, is missing or has not documented some obvious things (want to build tool tip text with a function that is called when the tip is displayed) and is a hefty download (partly because it appears to include a lot of stuff like rounded corner styling). Hopefully not seen as negative -- just trying to save someone else some time. Definitely worth considering but there are some downsides.

Comment: @Cymen, I can't speak for how things were circa Sept. of '10, but none of what you say is true any longer.  It is:  active, well documented, and allows for very customizable download sizes a la jQuery UI.

Answer (score 52):

This can be done easily with the mouseover event as well. I've done it and it doesn't take 200 lines at all. Start with triggering the event, then use a function that will create the tooltip.

```
$('span.clickme').mouseover(function(event) {
    createTooltip(event);               
}).mouseout(function(){
    // create a hidefunction on the callback if you want
    //hideTooltip(); 
});

function createTooltip(event){          
    $('<div class="tooltip">test</div>').appendTo('body');
    positionTooltip(event);        
};
```

Then you create a function that position the tooltip with the offset position of the DOM-element that triggered the mouseover event, this is doable with css.

```
function positionTooltip(event){
    var tPosX = event.pageX - 10;
    var tPosY = event.pageY - 100;
    $('div.tooltip').css({'position': 'absolute', 'top': tPosY, 'left': tPosX});
};
```

Comment: Simple and usefull, no need for a XX ko plugin when you can write it easily. PS : position:absolute is missing :)

Comment: You probably want to add "px" units to your integers. `'top': tPosY + 'px'` and so on.

Comment: $('span.klickme') - this is bad :)

Comment: I like your approach. Very easy way to do without using any external library

Answer (score 13):

Although qTip (the accepted answer) is good, I started using it, and it lacked some features I needed.

I then stumbled upon [PoshyTip](http://vadikom.com/demos/poshytip/) - it is very flexible, and really easy to use. (And I could do what I needed)

Answer (score 4):

Ok, after some work I'm able to get a "bubble" to pop up and go away at all the right times. There is a LOT of styling that needs to happen still but this is basically the code i used.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //--indicates the mouse is currently over a div
    var onDiv = false;
    //--indicates the mouse is currently over a link
    var onLink = false;
    //--indicates that the bubble currently exists
    var bubbleExists = false;
    //--this is the ID of the timeout that will close the window if the user mouseouts the link
    var timeoutID;

    function addBubbleMouseovers(mouseoverClass) {
        $("."+mouseoverClass).mouseover(function(event) {
            if (onDiv || onLink) {
                return false;
            }

            onLink = true;

            showBubble.call(this, event);
        });

        $("." + mouseoverClass).mouseout(function() {
            onLink = false;
            timeoutID = setTimeout(hideBubble, 150);
        });
    }

    function hideBubble() {
        clearTimeout(timeoutID);
        //--if the mouse isn't on the div then hide the bubble
        if (bubbleExists && !onDiv) {
             $("#bubbleID").remove();

             bubbleExists = false;
        }
    }

    function showBubble(event) {
        if (bubbleExists) {
            hideBubble();
        }

        var tPosX = event.pageX + 15;
        var tPosY = event.pageY - 60;
        $('<div ID="bubbleID" style="top:' + tPosY + '; left:' + tPosX + '; position: absolute; display: inline; border: 2px; width: 200px; height: 150px; background-color: Red;">TESTING!!!!!!!!!!!!</div>').mouseover(keepBubbleOpen).mouseout(letBubbleClose).appendTo('body');

        bubbleExists = true;
    }

    function keepBubbleOpen() {
        onDiv = true;
    }

    function letBubbleClose() {
        onDiv = false;

        hideBubble();
    }


    //--TESTING!!!!!
    $("document").ready(function() {
        addBubbleMouseovers("temp1");
    });
</script>
```

Here is a snippet of the html that goes with it:

```
<a href="" class="temp1">Mouseover this for a terribly ugly red bubble!</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

I have programmed an useful jQuery Plugin to create easily smart bubble popups with only a line of code in jQuery!

What You can do:
- attach popups to any DOM element!
- mouseover/mouseout events automatically managed!
- set custom popups events!
- create smart shadowed popups! (in IE too!)
- choose popup’s style templates at runtime!
- insert HTML messages inside popups!
- set many options as: distances, velocity, delays, colors…

Popup’s shadows and colorized templates are fully supported by
Internet Explorer 6+, Firefox, Opera 9+, Safari

You can download sources from
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqBubblePopup

Answer (score 4):

QTip has bug with jQuery 1.4.2. I had to switch to jQuery Bubble Pop up http://www.vegabit.com/jquery_bubble_popup_v2/#examples and it works great!

Answer (score 3):

Sounds to me you dn't want the mouse over events: you want the jQuery hover() event.

And what you seem to want is a "rich" tooltip, in which case I suggest [jQuery tooltip](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/).  With the bodyHandler option you can put arbitrary HTML in.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the super-quick response! I just skimmed through the documentation and I'm not sure there is an option to for the "tooltip" to stay in a fixed position so that you can move your mouse onto it and click a link. Have you used this before? In the meantime I'll download and start playing

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying to make a "bubble" that can
>   popup when the onmouseover event is
>   fired and will stay open as long as
>   the mouse is over the item that threw
>   the onmouseover event OR if the mouse
>   is moved into the bubble. My bubble
>   will need to have all manners of html
>   and styling including hyperlinks,
>   images, etc.

All those events fully managed by this plugin...

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqBubblePopup

Comment: This link is no longer good ...

Answer (score 2):

[ColorTip](http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2010/07/colortips-jquery-tooltip-plugin/colortips.html) is the most beautiful i've ever seen

Answer (score 2):

The new version 3.0 of the jQuery Bubble Popup plugin supports jQuery v.1.7.2, currently the latest and stable version of the most famous javascript library.

The most interesting feature of the 3.0 version is that You can use together jQuery & Bubble Popup plugin with any other libraries and javascript frameworks like Script.aculo.us, Mootols or Prototype because the plugin is completely encapsulated to prevent incompatibility problems;

jQuery Bubble Popup was tested and supports a lot of known and “unknown” browsers; see the documentation for the complete list.

Like previous versions, jQuery Bubble Popup plugin continues to be released under the MIT license; You are free to use jQuery Bubble Popup in commercial or personal projects as long as the copyright header is left intact.

download the latest version or visit live demos and tutorials at
http://www.maxvergelli.com/jquery-bubble-popup/

Answer (score 1):

Autoresize simple Popup Bubble

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <link href="bubble.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="bubble.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <br/><br/>
  <div class="bubbleInfo">
      <div class="bubble" title="Text 1">Set cursor</div>
  </div>
  <br/><br/><br/><br/>
  <div class="bubbleInfo">
      <div class="bubble" title="Text 2">Set cursor</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

bubble.js

```
$(function () {     
  var i = 0;
  var z=1;
  do{
    title = $('.bubble:eq('+i+')').attr('title');
    if(!title){
      z=0;
    } else {
       $('.bubble:eq('+i+')').after('<table style="opacity: 0; top: -50px; left: -33px; display: none;" id="dpop" class="popup"><tbody><tr><td id="topleft" class="corner"></td><td class="top"></td><td id="topright" class="corner"></td></tr><tr><td class="left"></td><td>'+title+'</td><td class="right"></td></tr><tr><td class="corner" id="bottomleft"></td><td class="bottom"><img src="bubble/bubble-tail.png" height="25px" width="30px" /></td><td id="bottomright" class="corner"></td></tr></tbody></table>');
       $('.bubble:eq('+i+')').removeAttr('title');
    }
    i++;
  }while(z>0)

  $('.bubbleInfo').each(function () {
    var distance = 10;
    var time = 250;
    var hideDelay = 500;        
    var hideDelayTimer = null;       
    var beingShown = false;
    var shown = false;
    var trigger = $('.bubble', this);
    var info = $('.popup', this).css('opacity', 0);        

    $([trigger.get(0), info.get(0)]).mouseover(function () {
      if (hideDelayTimer) clearTimeout(hideDelayTimer);
      if (beingShown || shown) {
        // don't trigger the animation again
        return;
      } else {
        // reset position of info box
        beingShown = true;

        info.css({
        top: -40,
        left: 10,
        display: 'block'
        }).animate({
        top: '-=' + distance + 'px',
        opacity: 1
        }, time, 'swing', function() {
          beingShown = false;
          shown = true;
        });
      }          
      return false;
    }).mouseout(function () {
      if (hideDelayTimer) clearTimeout(hideDelayTimer);
      hideDelayTimer = setTimeout(function () {
        hideDelayTimer = null;
        info.animate({
          top: '-=' + distance + 'px',
          opacity: 0
        }, time, 'swing', function () {
          shown = false;
          info.css('display', 'none');
        });
      }, hideDelay);
      return false;
    });
  }); 
});
```

bubble.css

```
/* Booble */
.bubbleInfo {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
}
.bubble {       
}
.popup {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    z-index: 50;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-size: .8em;
}
.popup td.corner {
    height: 13px;
    width: 15px;
}
.popup td#topleft { 
    background-image: url(bubble/bubble-1.png); 
} 
.popup td.top { 
    background-image: url(bubble/bubble-2.png); 
}
.popup td#topright { 
    background-image: url(bubble/bubble-3.png); 
}
.popup td.left { 
    background-image: url(bubble/bubble-4.png); 
}
.popup td.right { 
    background-image: url(bubble/bubble-5.png); 
}
.popup td#bottomleft { 
    background-image: url(bubble/bubble-6.png); 
}
.popup td.bottom { 
    background-image: url(bubble/bubble-7.png); 
    text-align: center;
}
.popup td.bottom img { 
    display: block; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
.popup td#bottomright { 
    background-image: url(bubble/bubble-8.png); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Tiptip](http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/tiptip-jquery-plugin) is also a nice library.

Answer (score 1):

You can use qTip for this; However you'd have to code a little for launching it on mouseover event; And in case you want a default watermark on your text fields, you'd have to use the watermark plugin...

I realized that this leads to lot of repetitive code; So I wrote a plugin on top of qTip that makes it really easy to attach informational popup to form fields. You can check it out here: https://bitbucket.org/gautamtandon/jquery.attachinfo

Hope this helps.