# Creating HTML/CSS based speech bubbles with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

In the design I was given by my PM, I need to create speech bubbles as a means of calling out features or providing help to the user.

[image: Speech bubble call out example]

The bubble should be able to handle any amount of text thrown at it. For example, it could be 15 words or a 150. Yes, that would be a big bubble.

The user clicks on the help button (?) and the bubble should fade in and not disturb the surrounding UI elements.

Comment: What have you come up with so far Amber?

Comment: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqBubblePopup

Comment: @jamie-dixon - At the moment, not much as this was dropped on my plate this morning. I have an idea of how the eventing on the click, the fade in are going to work. I'm a little fuzzy on how I'm going to "float it" and not disturbing what's around the bubble. What has me stumped the most is the rounded borders on the dox (likely going to be a `<div />`) and vertically centered carrot pointing to the help button.

Comment: d_r_w, the problem with that plugin was it required files to be installed off of the root and doesn't provide for a methods for changing that behavior. We have a coding practice of placing jQuery plugins in /js/jquery/plugins.

Comment: Similar/dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625920/jquery-popup-bubble

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it all with just css:
http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-speech-bubbles/

except the fading in part. But that is simple jquery.

also if you have everything working correctly and only can't figure out the rounded border you can try the css attribute `border-radius: #px;

it also has attributes for other browser compatibility:

```
-webkit-border-radius: #px; 
-moz-border-radius: #px;
```

Comment: You can do fading with CSS3 transitions. EG: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

Answer (score 0):

Pure CSS solution with rounded corners will be hard if you want this to work with IE8 and below. Be sure to test in all platforms before you implement that one.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed border-radius is not supported in IE8 and below. Instead you could use Sprint or PIE CSS as workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the height from the top to the button and than draw the height from the div with the content inside from it. To get the height of the div with the content inside, create a duplicate of outside the viewport with the same css-properties.

To get the bubble have a look at this:
http://www.ilikepixels.co.uk/drop/bubbler/