# how to popup single div on every mouseover in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have code like below, I want whenever mouse over anyof the label control a popup div appear and when mouse over from popup div itshould disappear in jquery

```
<div id="">

       <div id="1">
          <label control>
       </div>

       <div id="2">
          <asp label control>
       </div>

</div>
```

Hello but when i mouseover on tooltip it disappear. i will have some links on popup ,

same like on this website, whenever mouserover on any tag popup appears

Comment: Dont forget to mark answer as accpeted if you got the info you want

Comment: Hello but when i mouseover on tooltip it disappear. i will have some links on popup

Answer (score 1):

Make use of : [jQuery plugin: Tooltip](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/) will do the task easily for you.

you can also check this answer and get you task done : [jQuery Popup Bubble/Tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625920/jquery-popup-bubble)