# How to display a little window with onmouseover

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use this code to display some data when the mouse is over that link:

```
<span  id="ssd" onmouseover="this.T_WIDTH=210;this.T_TITLE='(0/0) mqe= ';"><a href='http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree_learning'>http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree_learning</a></span><br/>
```

Do you see something wrong because I can't make it work.

Comment: In your onmouseover the only thing you're doing is setting values to variables. There is no function there to do anything with those values.

Comment: try with [`jQuery tipsy`](http://www.jqueryplugins.com/plugin/165/)

Comment: do you want this URL to open in a window ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's get away from this DOM level 0 stuff:

```
var spSsd = document.getElementById("ssd");
spSsd.addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
     this.style.width = "240px";
     this.setAttribute("title", "(0/0) mqe");
});
```

I assume your `this.T_WIDTH=210` was supposed to set the width of the span, and `this.T_TITLE=(0/0) mqe` was supposed to set the title?  The code above should do that, just note that you need to set your span to **display:block** for this to work, since inline elements don't really have a width.

Just make sure you put this script at the **bottom** of your body; executing it in the head will give you a null error, since the span `ssd` will not have been created yet.  Or if you're using jQuery, you could put it in the `document.ready` function.

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions try the following

[jQuery Bubble Popup](http://www.vegabit.com/Examples/different-elements.html)

[JQuery Popup Bubble Question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625920/jquery-popup-bubble)