# Mouseover popup speech bubble

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup, mouseover

I'm new to javascript/css and would like to make a version of a mouseover popup similar to the one that displays over the underlined words here: http://st.japantimes.co.jp/essay/?p=ey20141219
I can see the code that is used, but I'm not sure where/how to add in my own speech bubble image when I edit the code for my own project.

Here is an example of the code used on the referenced page:

HTML:

```
<a style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="showChuPopup(event,'<b>’Twas</b><br />It was の省略');return false;" onmouseover="showChuPopup(event,'<b>’Twas</b><br />It was の省略');" onmouseout="endChuPopup();">’Twas</a>
```

Javascript:

```
function showChuPopup(e,text){
if(document.all)e = event;

var obj = document.getElementById('chu_popup');
var obj2 = document.getElementById('chu_popup_text');
obj2.innerHTML = text;
obj.style.display = 'block';
var st = Math.max(document.body.scrollTop,document.documentElement.scrollTop);/*
if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('safari')>=0)st=0;*/
var leftPos = e.clientX - 100;
if(leftPos<0)leftPos = 0;
obj.style.left = leftPos + 'px';
obj.style.top = e.clientY - obj.offsetHeight -1 + st + 'px';} function endChuPopup() {
document.getElementById('chu_popup').style.display = 'none';} function touchHandler(e){
document.getElementById('chu_popup').style.display = 'none';}
```

Thanks for any help or ideas.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Popup Bubble/Tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625920/jquery-popup-bubble-tooltip)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to go about this, but I'll recommend two options and provide links to both!

---

**First**, check out the answer on this question to see if this is what you want:

[jQuery Popup Bubble/Tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625920/jquery-popup-bubble-tooltip?rq=1)

---

**Second**, have you thought about just using a tooltip with CSS? They're not hard to implement at all, and you can absolutely bind data to them.

(Shamelessly stolen from: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp, I would recommend poking around here and also looking into Bootstrap if you're a beginner!)

```
<style>
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 150%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -60px;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent transparent black transparent;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
}
</style>

<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
</div>
```