# How to display a pop up data on mouse click event for the sphere objects which is overlayed on the 3D model(using Autodesk forge)

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have created a project to display a 3d model in the viewer(using Autodesk forge). On top of it I have added a scene to display two sphere objects as shown in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgnUG.png)
I want to add a mouse click event for the sphere objects – On click of the sphere objects I need to have a pop up data. As I am a beginner, I am stuck in this click event of the overlayed scene. This is the github link of my project for reference(https://github.com/vennilabalaraman/SphereClick). It will be helpful if I get solution for this. Thanks in advance.
This is my javascript and html code

```js
let viewer = null;

function setupViewer(divId, documentId, tokenFetchingUrl, exrtensionArray, AccessToken) {
    console.log('Entered setupViewer');
    let options = {
        env: 'AutodeskProduction',
        getAccessToken: (onGetAccessToken) => {
            fetch(tokenFetchingUrl)
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    let accessToken = AccessToken;
                    let expireTimeSeconds = data["expires_in"];
                    onGetAccessToken(accessToken, expireTimeSeconds);
                })
        }
    };

    var config3d = {extensions: exrtensionArray};
    Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, () => {
        viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(document.getElementById(divId), config3d);
        viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT,()=>{
     //Create Custom Geometry
     //alert("Under Custom Geom");
     var geom = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.05, 4, 5);
     var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xFF0000 });
     var sphereMesh = new THREE.Mesh(geom, material);
     var sphereMesh1 = new THREE.Mesh(geom, material);
     //sphereMesh1.position.set(11, 10, 30);
        sphereMesh.position.x = -5; sphereMesh.position.y = -0.8; sphereMesh.position.z = 1.8;
     sphereMesh1.position.x = -3.5; sphereMesh1.position.y = -1.5; sphereMesh1.position.z = 1.8;
     //Create Overlay scene

     if (!viewer.overlays.hasScene('my_scene')) {
      viewer.overlays.addScene('my_scene');
        }
        viewer.overlays.addMesh([sphereMesh], 'my_scene');
        viewer.overlays.addMesh([sphereMesh1], 'my_scene');
    });
        viewer.start();
        Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(documentId, onDocumentLoadSuccess, onDocumentLoadFailure);
      });

      function onDocumentLoadSuccess(doc) {
        var viewables = doc.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry();
        viewer.loadDocumentNode(doc, viewables).then(i => {
          // documented loaded, any action?
        });
      }
      
      function onDocumentLoadFailure(viewerErrorCode) {
        console.error('onDocumentLoadFailure() - errorCode:' + viewerErrorCode);
      }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Example</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no"/>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <!-- Autodesk Forge Viewer files -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/style.min.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.min.js"></script>


    <!-- Developer CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/main.css"/>
    <!-- Developer JS -->
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/js/extensions/markupExt.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="MyViewerDiv"></div>
    <script>
        let divId = "MyViewerDiv";
        let documentId = 'urn:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6bmlzaGFudF90ZXN0Ml8yMDIwXzA0XzMvZ2F0ZWhvdXNlLm53ZA';
        let tokenFetchingUrl = "https://9irt90dm6j.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod";
        let extensionArray = ['MarkUp3DExtension'];
        let AccessToken = "";
        setupViewer(divId, documentId, tokenFetchingUrl, extensionArray, AccessToken);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest to try the latest [SceneBuilder API](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Extensions/SceneBuilder/) of Viewer - you'd be able to append your own geometry and enjoy all the features that come out of the box with a bubble view (document model) like selecting, highlighting (rollover) and isolating etc with your own geometry...

```
const sphereGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry(new THREE.SphereGeometry(5, 8, 8));
const sphereMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: new THREE.Color(0, 1, 0) });
const sphereTransform = new THREE.Matrix4().compose(
  new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0),
  new THREE.Quaternion(0, 0, 0, 1),
  new THREE.Vector3(1, 1, 1)
);
const sphereFragId = modelBuilder.addFragment(sphereGeometry, sphereMaterial, sphereTransform);
modelBuilder.changeFragmentsDbId(sphereFragId, 12345); // Use this dbId in Viewer APIs as usual
```

See this tutorial [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/custom-models-forge-viewer) to get started ...

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Bryan Huang. As you have suggested, I have tried SceneBuilderAPI in my code. I can add sphere,cylinder or box objects similar to the tutorial link which you have shared. But still the problem exists in the mouse click event for the objects.

Comment: What I was suggesting was that you could then actually use Viewer's API to get the click events ([SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT event](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/selection-override)) and go from there ...

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with *Autodesk Forge* but a lot with *Three.js*. So on the high level you will need to:

1. Subscribe to the `click` event of the `MyViewerDiv`.
2. Perform a raycast into the scene to pick objects below the mouse cursor: [offial docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Raycaster), [another tutorial](https://riptutorial.com/three-js/example/17088/object-picking---raycasting).
3. If there was an intersection, show a popup using a dedicated librar. Some were discussed [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625920/jquery-popup-bubble-tooltip).

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Isolin. I have tried with this approach, it was working fine. I am facing issue only when I try it on the overlayed scene with 3Dmodel.

Comment: And what is the issue then?

Comment: I had to use the API provided by Autodesk forge for the selection event. Now it worked

Comment: Glad to hear that :)