# What are your favorite JavaScript libraries/scripts for creating tooltips on the web?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, client, tooltip

I've used jTip (jQuery plugin) and overLIB in the past.  Are there any others I should be looking into...any accepted "best" one?

Answer (score 1):

see this post [Recommendations for jQuery tooltips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543277/recommendations-for-jquery-tooltips)

Answer (score 1):

Remember, sometimes, a simple `<acronym title="long description">text</acronym>` is a good way to deal with that issue.

(Good) Browsers are displaying acronyms underlined and show the title attribute in a tooltip on mouse over.

You'll need some small CSS extra-rules to make it work on IE (at least on IE 6).

However, according to that tag name and [W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.2.1), `<acronym>` *should* only be used for acronyms (obviously!).

Note : You've also have the `<abbr>` tag with same behavior.