# Appearing tooltip without hovering mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

In the code below the tooltip appears upon hovering the mouse onto the text "hover your mouse".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p title="this is tooltip">hover your mouse</p>

</body>
```

Is there any way using JavaScript to appear the tooltip without hovering the mouse? Say upon the page gets loaded we want to display the tooltip of a button for 5 sec and then hiding the tooltip again.

This is what I tried (based on answers below) to at least display the tooltip without mouse hover, but does not do anything to tooltip

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p title="this is tooltip" id="my-hover">hover your mouse</p>
<script>


    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#my-hover').trigger('mouseover');
    }, 1000);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem. Describe your problem in more detail or include a minimal example in the question itself.*

Comment: Do you really mean it? Then what is the sense in giving it as a tooltip?

Comment: @sree I dont have room next to my button to display a text or div etc. I need to use tooltip for that.

Comment: @HashemQolami that was all you could offer?

Comment: @Cgraphics Absolutely not, but there are a lot of possibilities because of lack of *sufficient information*

Comment: @HashemQolami That close reason doesn't really apply either though. I'm not entirely sure why the close reasons were changed. The current list seems to be worse than they were before, and I often find myself struggling to find one that actually applies. This doesn't lack sufficient information - the problem statement is pretty clear (they want to show the tooltip for five seconds on page load, then have its functionality revert to normal) - what it lacks is sufficient evidence that they've actually tried to solve the problem first.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Totally agree.

Comment: @HashemQolami I updated my question. Now can you help or you just wanted to create trouble here for me?

Answer (score 1):

```
<p title="this is tooltip" id="my-hover">hover your mouse</p> 
    setTimeout(function () {
                $('#my-hover').trigger('mouseover');
            }, 10); 

    $('#my-hover').mouseover(function () {
         setTimeout(function () {
            $('#my-hover').show();}, 500);   

    });
```

This code will automatic fire a mouseover event.

Comment: They don't want to hide the paragraph. They want to display the tooltip (what you get when you hover your mouse over it) for five seconds, then hide that. The paragraph should still be visible throughout.

Comment: This is what the user want. User is asking for a system which can make the tooltip appear and then disappear. +1 for Kaptan. Good Answer. :)

Comment: @AbdurRahim No this is not what I wanted! I did not want to hide the paragraph! I wanted to display tooltip for 5 sec upon load of page then hide the tooltip ( I clearly said tooltip)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('element').trigger('mouseover');
```

this based on Script

Comment: Doesn't work. Also not sure where `cert-small` came from since that's not part of the HTML in the question.

Comment: i update answer you must place your element cert-samll is example

Comment: also you must use tooltip javascript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/543277/recommendations-for-jquery-tooltips

Comment: I know `cert-small` was an example, I just don't know *why* you chose it as an example. The code in your question *doesn't work* even with a valid selector for an element.

Comment: i test code in my website `cert-small` and run this code in firebug and give feed back if you want send you url and test it in firebug

Comment: I don't know what you tested in your website, but it wasn't that single line of code in your answer, because that *doesn't work*. I've tested it, it does nothing, your answer is incorrect. If there's also a plugin that needs to be initialized on the element first, as your comment suggests, **you need to add that information to your answer**.

Comment: i'm sorry my English no good, o O no not incorrect i say `this is based on Script` & i test it on other website on class have tool tip , it enable when mouse Over and with this code you call mouse over event

Comment: @samankhademi it is not really working! It doenst do anything to th etooltip!

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery UI Tooltip

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css" />

        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p title="this is tooltip" id="tooltip">hover your mouse</p>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $( "#tooltip" ).tooltip({ content: "this is tooltip" }).tooltip("open");
            setTimeout(function () { $("#tooltip").tooltip("close");}, 5000);
        </script>  
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean : "not doing anything..."?